# Где  скачать физический 2d движок?

Tags: 2d, c++

Уже долго борюсь с отскоком шара об стенку, а тут выяснилось, что шар еще должен попадать в предмет, сбивать его на какое-то расстояние, да и еще правильно отскочить. Может кто знает, где можно скачать бесплатный физический движок на СС++? Желательно, чтоб движок не просил подключения никакого - DirectX или OpenGL. По сути этот "движок" должен только принимать параметры, отрисовка и прочее должно производиться моими функциями. Спасибо.

Comment: См. ответ на вопрос [задачи математического моделирования](http://hashcode.ru/questions/71376/задачи-математического-моделирования)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтоп

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**http://box2d.org**](http://box2d.org/)

Comment: Вообще, если вы не можете такой пример реализовать самостоятельно, то не стоит начинать пользоваться чужими движками.

Comment: Вот блин, проще похоже написать самому чем это понять...
Спасибо!